# Parallelism in (I)Python with large blocks of data

Tags: numpy, multiprocessing, ipython

I've been toiling with threads and processes for a while now to try to speed up my very parallel job in IPython. I'm not sure how much detail about the function I'm calling is useful, so here's a bash but ask if you need more.

My function's call signature looks like

```
def intersplit_array(ob,er,nl,m,mi,t,ti,dmax,n0=6,steps=50):
```

Basically, `ob`, `er` and `nl` are parameters for observed values and `m`,`mi`,`t`,`ti` and `dmax` are parameters that represent models against which the observations will be compared. (`n0` and `steps` are fixed numerical parameters for the function.) The function loops through all the models in `m` and, using associated information in `mi`, `t`, `ti` and `dmax`, calculates a probability that this model matches. Note that `m` is quite big: it's a list of about 700 000 22x3 NumPy arrays. `mi` and `dmax` are of similar sizes. If releant, my normal IPython instance uses about 25% of system memory in `top`: 4GB of my 16GB of RAM.

I've tried to parallelize this in two ways. First, I tried to use the `parallel_map` function given over [at the SciPy Cookbook](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Multithreading). I made the call

```
P = parallel_map(lambda i: intersplit_array(ob,er,nl,m[i+1],mi[i:i+2],t[i+1],ti[i:i+2],dmax[i+1],range(1,len(m)-1))
```

which runs, and provides the correct answer.  Without the `parallel_` part, this is just the result of applying the function one by one to each element. But this is slower than using a single core. I guess this is related to the Global Interpreter Lock?

Second, I tried to use a `Pool` from `multiprocessing`. I initialized a pool with

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool(6)
```

and then tried to call my function with

```
P = p.map(lambda i: intersplit_array(ob,er,nl,m[i+1],mi[i:i+2],t[i+1],ti[i:i+2],dmax[i+1],range(1,len(m)-1))
```

First, I get an error.

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 319, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

Having a look in `top`, I then see all the extra `ipython` processes, each of which is apparently taking up 25% of RAM (which can't be so, because I've still got 4GB free) and using 0% CPU. I presume it isn't doing anything. I can't use IPython, either. I tried Ctrl-C for a while, but gave up once I got passed the 300th pool worker.

Comment: can you use m = a single 700000 x 22 x 3 numpy array and apply vectorized numpy operations to it in intersplit_array()?

Comment: I did try that, but IIRC that gave me memory errors. I think some of the broadcasting that I did made new arrays that were too large. It may have been a design flaw, but I left it because speed wasn't an issue until quite recently. I might give that another look too.

Comment: if intermediate arrays are too large; you could perform the computations on slices e.g., 700 slices with the size 1000 each. numpy arrays should release GIL during vectorized operations, so you could use `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` that uses threads instead of processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work *not* interactively?

`multiprocessing` doesn't play well interactively, because of the way it splits processes.  This is also why you had trouble killing it because it spawned so many processes.  You would have to keep track of the master process to cancel it.

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html):

> **Note**
>   Functionality within this package requires that the `__main__` module be importable by the children. This is covered in *[Programming guidelines](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming)* however it is worth pointing out here. This means that some examples, such as the `multiprocessing.Pool` examples will not work in the interactive interpreter.
>   `...`
>   If you try this it will actually output full tracebacks interleaved in a semi-random fashion, and then you may have to stop the master process somehow.

The best solution is probably to just run it as a script from the command line.  Alternatively, [IPython has its own system for parallel computing](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/parallel_intro.html), but I've never used it.

Comment: Somehow, amidst all my Googling with keywords like "python" and "parallel", I hadn't found iPython's parallel system, which I've now used. So thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: Glad to be of help, @Warrick.  Was it successful?  I haven't tried it.

Comment: Yip, after a bit of fiddling with the function call, it works like a bomb. My only worry now is that sometimes the cluster nodes also run out of memory, but I'm looking into that now.